# Unhandled Exception from Try - Catch Block

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have looked at the other questions related to this problem but I do not see answer that helps me (or perhaps more to the point that I understand).

This code:

```
   public static Bitmap GetLibraryObjectImage(Guid guid) {
            try {
                string tempPath = GetLibraryObjectImagePath(guid);
                if (tempPath != string.Empty) {
                    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tempPath);
                    var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    return (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
            }
            catch {
                return (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\na.bmp");
            }

            return (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\na.bmp");
        }
```

is intended to deal with any situation in which the image file is not found or is invalid in some other way.  I have not identified any specific exception type in the hope that it will catch anything.

For one of my users it threw this exception:

> Invalid Parameter.
>   At System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream
>   stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
>   At System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
>   At ScruffyDuck.AirportDesignEditor.Helpers.U.GetLibraryObjectImage(Guid
>   guid)

I have seen this before in other situations in try-catch blocks where handling images.  I thought that the above try-catch would get everything including unmanaged exceptions but perhaps I am wrong.

I have no idea regarding the circumstances causing the exception but I really don't want my app to crash and burn even if I am trying to manage the problems.  It was caught by my global exception handler but of course by then it is a bit late.

Many thanks for any insight into avoiding this

Comment: How certain are you that this user was *really* using that version of your code? I would be very surprised to see this occur.

Comment: Jon  That is a very good point.  We have released a number of small updates recently.  Looking at the version he is using I THINK I am looking at the right code.  However I am going back into the repository now to check

Comment: This is why, if the software is in-house, I prefer to generate PDBs for even Release configurations; it'll give you line numbers which, if they don't match the latest source, indicate an outdated software version.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the code present in the version that the user reported the unhandled exception with.

Comment: @KeithS - good point I had not considered that, although in this case the user is using the code above and the log shows this along with the unhandled exception

Comment: Could it be that the `Image.FromFile` uses `Image.FromStream` internally? I don't have any decompiler at hand to check it out but if this is so then maybe it is the `Image.FromFile` from inside the `catch` which is responsible for throwing the exception.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Reflector doesn't show it calling `FromStream`, it calls some native method for loading...

Comment: The stack trace indicates that the call from user code was made directly to Image.FromStream(). There would be an additional Image.FromFile() call between GetLibraryObjectImage(Guid guid) and Image.FromStream(Stream stream) otherwise.

Comment: Clutching at straws here, does .FromStream do anything in a lazy-evaluation or async manner that somehow bypasses the catch? I'm not even sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KeithS mentioned in the comments, the stack trace is showing that the exception is originating in the `Image.FromStream` method. Have you verified that all of the code leading up to that call is correctly returning the expected data? The file path must exist (or the `File.ReadAllBytes` would have thrown an exception) and the `MemoryStream` constructor is returning a valid stream (or it would have thrown an exception) but is it possible that the data in the memory stream isn't actually an image?

Also, you might want to try using the `File.OpenRead` method instead. This returns a `FileStream` so you can pass that directly in to the `Image.FromStream` method. This would look similar to the following code. (I changed it some to use a `using` statement and only have a single return statement.)

```
public static Bitmap GetLibraryObjectImage(Guid guid) 
{ 
   Bitmap bitmap = null;

   try
   { 
      string tempPath = GetLibraryObjectImagePath(guid); 
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempPath) 
      {
         using (var stream = File.OpenRead(tempPath))
         {
            bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);
         }
      } 
   } 
   catch
   { 
      bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\na.bmp"); 
   }

   if (bitmap == null)
   {
      bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\na.bmp"); 
   }

   return bitmap;
}
```